# java date format - GMT 0700 (PDT)

Tags: java, simpledateformat

This is the date format that I need to deal with

```
Wed Aug 21 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

But I don't get what the last two parts are. Is the `GMT-0700` fixed? Should it be something like this?

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT-0700' (z)");
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it is not fixed. It is a TimeZone. You can match it with `Z` in the date format.

To be more precise, in [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) formats :

- `Z` matches the `-0700` part.
- `GMT` is fixed. Escape it with some quotes.
- z matches the `PDT` part. (PDT = Pacific Daylight Time).
- The parenthesis around PDT are fixed. Escape them with parenthesis.

You can parse your date with the following format :

```
EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z '('z')'
```

**Another remark** : `Wed Aug` contains the day and month in English so you must use an english locale with your SimpleDateFormat **or the translation will fail**.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("*format*", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: wait, i don't get it. According to the document: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html, `z` matches `GMT` part, and `Z` matches the `-0700` part.

Comment: According to this doc, `z` can match `GMT-08:00`, not `GMT-0800`. That's why you must isolate the `GMT` part manually. `z` can also catch `GMT` alone but it would be considered as `GMT+00:00`. Hence, it would not make sense to have another `Z` (`GMT+00:00 -0700` => 2 Timezones).

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo. I mean `z` matches `PDT`, and `Z` matches `-0700`. I think you should switch `z` and `Z` here, is it right?

Comment: True! (I edited) Actually, that code worked by chance and I found why : `z` is the `General time zone` but the javadoc tells that for parsing, simple timezones are accepted and conversely.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the Javadoc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

For this example: `Wed Aug 21 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)`, you'd want this format:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class JavaDate {

  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

    String s= "Wed Aug 21 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
      new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'z '('Z')'");
    Date d = sdf.parse (s);
    System.out.println ("Date=" + d + "...");
  }
}
```

> EXAMPLE OUTPUT: Date=Tue Aug 20 23:00:00 PDT 2013...

Thanx to Arnaud Denoyelle above for his edits!