# In Clojure , how do you output a date like this 'Tue, 15-Jan-2013 21:47:38 GMT'?

Tags: datetime, clojure, jodatime

This date format is used in [HTTP Cookie Expires field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age).

This is my code so far

```
(ns cookie-handler
  (:require[clj-time.format :as f])
  (:import (org.joda.time DateTimeZone)))

(def custom-formatter2 
  (f/formatter "EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz" (DateTimeZone/forID "Etc/GMT")))
```

I invoke this in repl

```
(f/unparse custom-formatter2 (c/to-date-time  (.. (Calendar/getInstance) (getTime) )))
```

And this is what I get : "Thu, 23-Apr-2015 16:20:22 +00:00"

How do I initialize formatter so that it outputs a date string  like "Thu, 23-Apr-2015 16:20:22 GMT"

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: I think his question is in the title, but it would be helpful if it was also in the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a java version of this issue at [java date format - GMT 0700 (PDT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493528/java-date-format-gmt-0700-pdt)

If all you want is to have GMT at the end of the formatted date string, you can add those characters to the end of the format string

```
(def custom1 (f/formatter-local "EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'"))
(def formatted-date-1 (f/unparse custom1 (t/now)))
```

"Thu, 23-Apr-2015 19:12:58 GMT"

If you really need GMT followed by the offset, the same idea applies

```
(def custom2 (f/formatter-local "EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'z"))
(def today (t/to-time-zone (t/now) (t/time-zone-for-offset -6)))
(def formatted-date-2 (f/unparse custom-formatter today))
```

"Thu, 23-Apr-2015 13:12:58 GMT-06:00"

Answer (score 0):

I use the following in a [library](https://github.com/listora/ring-congestion/blob/master/src/congestion/responses.clj#L9) of mine that needs to output HTTP-spec compliant timestamps:

```
(def ^:private time-format (f/formatter "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"))

(defn- time->str
  [time]
  (str (f/unparse time-format time) " GMT"))
```

You can probably include `GMT` in the format string like G_A suggested, but I haven't tried that.

I do think that using [`f/formatter`](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time/blob/master/src/clj_time/format.clj#L41) rather than [`f/formatter-local`](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time/blob/master/src/clj_time/format.clj#L57) is important though, so that your local timestamp gets converted to UTC before it's converted to a string.