# java GMT datetimeparse

Tags: java, zoneddatetime

I have a string like the following

```
Fri May 31 2019 05:08:40 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

I want to convert this to something like `yyyy-MM-dd`.

I tried this.

```
String date1 = "Fri May 31 2019 05:08:40 GMT-0700 (PDT)";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" ).withLocale( Locale.US );

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( date1 , f );
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate();
DateTimeFormatter fLocalDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
String output = ld.format( fLocalDate ) ;
```

I am getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 
'Fri May 31 2019 05:08:40 GMT-0700 (PDT)' could not be parsed at index 13
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The pattern of your `DateTimeFormatter` doesn't fit the format of your string.

Comment: Can you tell me the exact pattern which will convert the Date in GMT format to IST

Comment: As an aside your way of formatting into `yyyy-MM-dd` is overly complicated. You just need `String output = zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patter of your formater is wrong. Year is missing (`"yyyy"`) and timezone is not matching. To match it you need to use both `z` and `Z` you also need to add unmatched text for GMT, like `"'GMT'Z (z)"`.

Try this:

```
"E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (z)"
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493528/java-date-format-gmt-0700-pdt) you can use following pattern:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String date1 = "Fri May 31 2019 05:08:40 GMT-0700 (PDT)";
    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z '('z')'" ).withLocale( Locale.US );

    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( date1 , f );
    LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate();
    DateTimeFormatter fLocalDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
    String output = ld.format( fLocalDate ) ;
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Output:

> 2019-05-31

Answer (score -1):

Since you need only **yyyy-MM-dd** formatted date, try this code:

```
   String date1 = "Fri May 31 2019 05:08:40 GMT-0700";

   //this format is good enough to read required data from your String
   DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");

   //format you require as final output
   DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

   //convert String to date ( with required attributes ) and then format to target
   System.out.println(df2.format(df1.parse(date1)));
```

Comment: When java.time, the modern Java date and time API is asked about, please don’t bring on the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Comment: Thanks @Ole. Query was about converting String to the target format. The logic I put would work though. I think I missed something..

Comment: It’s not that your answer isn’t correct. I believe it is. It’s just poor advice (the tag also seems to suggest that the questioner wants to use `ZonedDateTime`, as s/he already tries, and which is a good idea).